# Does forwardingAddresses().create require a GSuite account instead of a personal gmail account?

Tags: gmail-api

When calling the service.users().settings().forwardingAddresses().create function, I get the error:

"Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority"

I've been using credentials via OAuth2 using my personal gmail account.  Because of this "domain-wide authority" requirement, does that imply that I can not use the *create()* function on my personal, non-GSuite account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. In this case due to security reasons you can only use this method with service accounts that have been granted with domain wide authority, and this can only be configured in the Google Workspace (G Suite) Admin Console.

This is also described in the official documentation of this method from the Gmail API:

> This method is only available to service account clients that have been delegated domain-wide authority.

#### References:

- [Method: users.settings.forwardingAddresses.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.forwardingAddresses/create#:%7E:text=This%20method%20is%20only%20available%20to%20service%20account%20clients%20that%20have%20been%20delegated%20domain%2Dwide%20authority.)
- [Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. And I've seen that documentation but it is a FAR CRY from being clear about what I asked about.  Someone at Google should fix that documentation to be more clear so it says "This will not work with a basic Gmail account.  A G Suite account is required!"